# python code runs in standalone function but not as part of class

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python 3.3.5 I am building a class out of some code that works as standalone functions, but it aborts without an error message when the class version is run. It relies on a 3rd party package pcFastDB, distributed as a pyd.

```
unit1.py
import sys
import pcFastDB as p3

def get_context():
    return p3.pcContext.create()

def get_DB(ctx, dbName):
    return p3.pcDB.open(ctx, dbName)
.. more..
```

can be used as:

```
ctx = get_context()
db = get_DB(ctx, 'tester')
..do things with db
```

but

```
Unit2.py
import pcFastDB as p3
class DBOperation(object):
    def __init__(self, DB_name):
        '''
        Get the context, open the database and fill a channel list
        '''
        self.ctx = p3.pcContext.create()
        print('Context ' + str(self.ctx ))
        print(' - opening ' + DB_name)
        self.db = p3.pcDB.open(self.ctx, DB_name)  #aborts here
        print('DB opened successfully...' +str(self.db))
```

aborts silently when I try to open the DB.

```
db = DBOperation('tester')
```

The tester db exists and is in the project folder where I am running it.

There is no exception, no error, it just stops executing. PyDev doesn't like the pyd file very well. I don't get any code insight so debugging is kind of mysterious, but in IPython3 I can see all of the functions and class members, so I know its ok. Unfortunately debugging in IPython3 is an unfathomable mystery to me.

Anyway, I know that I am calling the right functions and I know the functions work, because it all works fine in Unit1, it just doesn't work as a class member. Is this even possible?

I've broken the DB lines out of the **init** and called them separately, and I've broken ctx out of the class and passed it into the functions but that doesn't work either. It behaves identically when run from within PyDev, IPython3 or the command line.

Any ideas?

Comment: show code where u make `DBOperation` Object.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal I've added the code into the question

Comment: How does class GeoDBOperation relate to the class DBOperation ?

Comment: @PaulMitchell Same thing,sorry, I've fixed it. I've obfuscated the code (badly) because of a  restrictive NDA

Comment: I assume you just did copy and paste operations between the working part and the class part - so no chance of typo ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta, yes that's right, and I've checked a dozen times!

Comment: Could it be a problem of not properly closing a previous instance ? What do you mean by "stop executing" ? If under command line python the interpreter ends and you are back in shell ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta yes exactly that.

Comment: Then I think you should try to see (or ask) what could generate such a crash in `pcFastDB.pcDB.open` ... no cleverer idea.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, I've gotten it working by basically rewriting the identical code into a new module. There seems to have been something weird with the file itself. I'm blaming PyDev.

Marc